# How to create and send apache cxf SoapMessage with cxf Messgae?

Tags: java, spring, apache, web-services, cxf

I'm using IntellijIDEA and I have project for testing SOAP WS. I have xml and msg file for sending. How can I cast this file into cxf Message and cxf SoapMessage for sending? This is my method, which return SoapMessage:

```
public SoapMessage getMessage(File file) throws Exception{
 Message msg;
 msg.setContent(File.class, file);
 SoapMessage message = new SoapMessage(msg);
 return message;
}
```

But if I try call this method, I see this:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

I try send this msg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <Test>
      <msg>Test</msg>
    </Test>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

UPD:
What need to msg initiallistion?

```
Message msg = new Message(){...}?
```

It use for cast my *.msg file into SoapMessage and send it into SOAP WS

Comment: Look at your code. You need to initialise msg.

Comment: @rghome how correct initialise msg?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can test SOAP based web service

1. Using SOAP UI client - it will be easy
2. We can generate the java code using Maven plugin and start consuming the service from main class.
3. Use wsimport command of Java

   wsimport -keep http://localhost:9090/ws/hello?wsdl

   ```
   URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9090/ws/hello?wsdl");
   //1st argument service URI, refer to wsdl document above
   //2nd argument is service name, refer to wsdl document above
   QName qname = new QName("http://ws.service.com/", "HelloWorldImplService");
   Service service = Service.create(url, qname);

   HelloWorld hellObj = service.getPort(HelloWorld.class);
   ```

Using obj call appropriate method.

We no need to construct the SOAP message manually.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, but I need to use  to use cxf Message and cxf SoapMessage according to the requirement specifications

Answer (score 0):

I needed to work on something similar, here is what i've done:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.Soap12;
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage;
import org.apache.cxf.headers.Header;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

@RunWith(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class SOAPMessageTest {

    @Test
    public void emptyHeaderTest() {
        SoapMessage soapMessage = new SoapMessage(Soap12.getInstance());

        List<Header> headers = soapMessage.getHeaders();
        assertThat(headers.size(), is(0));
    }
}
```

Adjust this code to add content to `soapMessage` object as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to instanciate a soapMessage like this ?

```
Reader reader = new StringReader(body);
    XMLStreamReader xmlReader = null;
    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance(); // Or newFactory()
    try {
      xmlReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(reader);
    } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SoapMessage soapMessage = new SoapMessage(Soap11.getInstance());
    soapMessage.setContent(XMLStreamReader.class, xmlReader);
```